# window.opener is null (iOS 12.3.1 Safari and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, ios, window.opener

There's a `target=_blank` link. A script in the linked page uses `window.opener`, and this has worked for years, but now it's broken on iOS because `window.opener` is `null`. What can I do?

There are plenty of old (some *very* old) "window.opener is null" questions, and a [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136610) that was closed in 2016. This seems to be a problem that comes and goes with versions. It has a lot of variants, and no solution I can see that actually works. Key differences between my situation and some of the older questions:

- I don't have a cross-domain link.
- I see the null value in both Safari and Chrome, where others saw it in one but not the other.
- I have `target=_blank`, not `window.open()`

Answer (score 10):

After much searching, I found this:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190481

> Summary: Experiment: target=_blank on anchors should imply rel=noopener

and this:

https://webkit.org/blog/8475/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-68/

> Changed target="_blank" on anchors to imply rel="noopener"

From the amount of complaints I received from iPhone users, I'm pretty sure this breaking change has appeared in the stable release of Safari, even though those links labeled "experimental" and "preview" are the only documentation I can find about it.

Mozilla has documented a similar feature for Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Experimental_features#Security) but unlike Apple, their documentation clearly and correctly labels it as an experiment that is not enabled in the stable release.

To get the old behavior back, you need to add `rel="opener"` to the `<a>` element. MDN mentions this, not on the [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) page where I'm looking when `window.opener` stops working, but  on a page called [Link types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types), which I was only able to find after I knew the answer already. They have it marked "experimental, do not use in production code" but I don't think I have a choice.

Comment: works like a charm in chrome. thank you sir