# Outlook for Mac 16.38 Add-in Dialogs fail to post message to parent

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

Upgraded to Outlook for Mac 16.38 from the 'Insider Fast' channel and now seeing a bug in our Outlook add-in where dialogs opened using displayDialogAsync (and not displayed in iFrames) are failing to send messages back to their parent.

**Example code in Dialog**

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
  try {
    Office.context.ui.messageParent('result');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error: ' + e);
  }
}
```

- Can see from stepping through using the debugger that Office.initialize function is never entered. Tried changing to Office.onReady but no change.

Tried scaling back to just using the browser method window.opener.postMessage and can see that fails because window.opener is null. Can see a question around Safari experimenting with setting noopener on a tags which could be related ([window.opener is null (iOS 12.3.1 Safari and Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060721/window-opener-is-null-ios-12-3-1-safari-and-chrome)? Could that be causing Office.initialize to fail? Tried window.parent.postMessage but it did not work either.

This should be reproducible on Outlook for Mac 16.38 with any Outlook add-in that launches a dialog using displayDialogAsync (not in an iFrame) that tries to send a message back to its parent.

Looking for any suggested workarounds, or confirmation from add-in team that logic changed here that would break this.

Outlook for Mac Version: 16.38.20050602.

- Was previously working in Outlook for Mac 16.36.20041300.

Comment: We are not able to reproduce the issue, can you share your OS version? If possible, please share your add-in manifest (or stripped down version of add-in), we can try it out in our environment.

Comment: Also which Outlook JS version or link is being used in your app?

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but we are experiencing an issue that looks very similar after upgrading MacOS to version 10.15.5. The add-in worked fine before and still works fine on Windows. We're loading OfficeJS using https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js